# Scripts are loading multiple times and hell of a warnings in console

Tags: javascript, webpack, pixi.js

I am building a game in `PIXI.JS` using `webpack` as a module bundler. Honestly i had made the game without `webpack` and it's running perfectly but i have to install some npm packages for this project and for that i have added `webpack` to my project and copy paste all the code. but having issues.

The problem i am facing is that i have a some code in my `app.js` which is running multiple times. Although it's not in a loop and it's declared globally below is the code in my `app.js`

```
`// CREATING GAME DIV
const game = document.createElement("div");
// ADDING ID
game.id = "game-container";
// APPENDING TO BODY
document.body.appendChild(game);

export const app = new PIXI.Application({
 width: window.innerHeight * (5 / 3),
 height: window.innerHeight,
});

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  app.view.width = window.innerHeight * (5 / 3);
  app.view.height = window.innerHeight;
});

game.appendChild(app.view);`
```

The above code is pretty simple to understand but let me explain this code is making a div and appending it to body and then creating a `PIXI.Application` which is a canvas and appending it to `div`

The webpack bundle this code and when i run the production code check below pic

[image showing how many divs get created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2YaY.png)

If you notice i have some `h1` tags and they are only three because in my index.js i have below code

```
`import './style.css';

const fontBoogaloo = document.createElement('h1');
const fontBarlow = document.createElement('h1');
const fontLuckiestGuy = document.createElement('h1');
fontBarlow.textContent = 'WORDFALL';
fontBoogaloo.textContent = 'WORDFALL';
fontLuckiestGuy.textContent = 'WORDFALL';
fontBarlow.classList.add('font-barlow');
fontBoogaloo.classList.add('font-boogaloo');
fontLuckiestGuy.classList.add('font-luckiest-guy');
document.body.appendChild(fontBarlow)
document.body.appendChild(fontBoogaloo)
document.body.appendChild(fontLuckiestGuy);`
```

Self explanatory code, so this code is running only once but the code in `app.js` is running multiple times.

and there are hell of a warnings in console let me show you

[hell of a warnings in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNrtY.png)

i think this is related to pixi.js and nothing to do with webpack. i have tried uncomment all the code and use `console.log('calling code')` to check if the issue is in the code but no even a single `console.log` is being called 30 times.

The issue i think is in the webpack because as i said i have build this game with same code and it's running fine. here is my `webpack.config.js` in case you need it [click here](https://gist.github.com/zohaibkhan-420/bc6b09e88543383ac9953fd600a6d8b3)

I am not expert in webpack so please feel free to ask my for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using live server extension
install webpack server plugin by `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server`
then add the following code in webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
  static: './dist',
},

optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
},
```

run `webpack serve --open` to start the server and everything will be good.